# how to create something to receive the data from a page in a tomcat server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, tomcat

I've been seeing lots of examples of `POST`ing and `GET`ing using `AJAX`, but I don't see many examples on how to receive that information on the server side, specially with a tomcat server. I have this page, and I would like to know what should I have to receive/handle that information on server-side (Tomcat)?

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function() {
  alert("file has been succesfully sent");
  var data = new FormData();
  var cssData = $("#custom-css-text").val();
  data.append("custom_css", cssData);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'myserver',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
      alert("file has been succesfully sent");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
textarea {
  border-style: outset;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <textarea id="custom-css-text">testing</textarea>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create a Servlet to handle that request in Tomcat. The most barebones way to do that would be to [create a war file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html).

Eclipse can usually set up one of these projects for you pretty quickly, and the way it works is by using a web.xml to map urls to java classes.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ServletServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>weblogic.servlet.ServletServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ServletServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/myservlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The above snippet, taken from the 'create a war file' link, will associate the class `weblogic.servlet.ServletServlet` with the endpoint `http://<server>:<port>/myservlet/` on the server you deploy the war file to.

The class itself just needs to extend HttpServlet, and you can override the `doGet()` method.

Any `GET` request to anything on your servlet's path will enter this method, and Tomcat will populate the request's information as necessary. You can then take the `Writer` out of the response object and write data to it, which, when your method returns, will be sent back to the client.

As an example for your case:

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>CSSServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.foo.CSSServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CSSServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/myserver/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

CSSServlet.java

```
public class CSSServlet extends HttpServlet{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    response.setContentType("text/html");//I'm not sure if 'text/css' is valid here. Might be worth trying.
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(myCss); //Get your css initialized into this var.
    }
}
```

See [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm) for another quick intro.

Comment: I have been learning a lot about servlets, I even downloaded Eclipse EE and created successfully some examples, but I don't know how to deploy it on my already running server. Thanks for helping and giving me that complete example :)

Comment: No problem. I think if you take a look at this link (http://www.openscope.net/2010/01/25/war-deployment-file-structure/) it should help with putting together a war. There are a few automated ways to do it too (maven archetypes, I think Eclipse can also).

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna take a look at it :)